# MapStruct+Spring+Junit : Inject mapper into service class test

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mapstruct

I am using Spring Boot, MapStruct (1.5.3.Final) and JUnit.
I want to inject a mapper into a service class test.
I don't want to stub this mapper (when(..).thenReturn(...)).

I have tried many things et read multiple posts on Stackoverflow but I find anything.

**My Mapper :**

```
@Mapper(
        componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING,
        injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR
)
public interface ReservationMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    Reservation getReservationFrom(NewReservationSentByClient reservationData);

    ExistingReservation getExistingReservationFrom(Reservation reservation);
}
```

**The service using this mapper :**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class StandardReservationService implements ReservationService{
    private final ReservationMapper reservationMapper;
  ...
```

**The test class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={ReservationMapper.class})
public class StandardReservationServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private ReservationRepository reservationRepositoryMock;
    @Autowired
    private ReservationMapper reservationMapperMock;
    @MockBean
    private ReservationRulesRepository reservationRulesRepositoryMock;
    @Autowired
    private StandardReservationService service;


    @ParameterizedTest
    @EnumSource(ReservationSource.class)
    public void ...
```

**pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TESTS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.17</source>
                    <target>1.17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I tried :

- Pass ReservationMapperImpl.class in @SpringBootTest(classes={..}) but when I clean-install this implementation is not found
- Instanciate manually ReservationMapperImpl but same problem when I clean-install
- ...etc

If posible I don't want to use @SpringBootTest because I am writing unit test and so I don't need context.. but I don't want to create manually object mapped and stub it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have no chance but to use a test with a spring context since you are using the Spring component model. I think the problem is, that the actual test does not scan the implementation of your mapper (`ReservationMapperImpl`).

I would suggest that you use a component scan for your test on the package of your mapper. You don't need to use `@SpringBooTest` for this, you can also use `@SpringJunitConfig(TestMappingConfig.class)` with an example test config like this:

```
@ComponentScan("package.of.the.mapper")
public class YouTestMappingConfig {

}
```

This will scan both, the `ReservationMapper` which will not be picked up, because it has no `@Component|Service|Bean` annotation, but the `ReservationMapperImpl` which has a `@Component` annotation and will be picked up for your test application context.

Answer (score -1):

You should try it with

```
private ReservationMapper reservationMapper = Mappers.getMapper(ReservationMapper.class);
```

and remove the `@Autowired` annotation. Tis should give yout the real implementation of the mapper.

Comment: I exactly did what you said and it doesn't works, I have the error :`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '...StandardReservationServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type '...StandardReservationService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Comment: In that case you could try and add the `@Spy` annotation

Comment: Or try and inject the here created mapper by constructor injection in the required service

Comment: I don't understand your last comment

Comment: You dont neccessarily have to use the @Autowired annotation to get a Serivce you can simply create in you test like you would usually generate a java class by using `new`. The dependencies of that service then can be satisfied manually by injecting them ..... On another note you should replace `@SpringBootTest(classes={ReservationMapper.class})` with `@SpringBootTest`. Your latest error message indicates that you dont have the required servcies available in the test environment. By explicitly adding the `classes` keyword all other classes are excluded by default.,

Comment: Firstly thank you @GJohannes. Secondly I resolved the problem, it was maybe due to the fact that Mapstruct didn't generate the mapper implementation (nothing in target/Generated-sources/annotations), I modified the pom.xml (replace 1.17 by 1.8 in plugin>configuration>source and target) and it works (without using context : `@extendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` + `@InjectMocks` + `@Spy` + `MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this)`).